# how to make our own Point Type with PCL 1.9

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I was following this [tutorial](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/adding_custom_ptype.html#adding-custom-ptype) to make it. But I think it is deprecated since you have to

```
#include <pcl/memory.h>
```

Which has been remove since PCL 1.8. I didn't find other tutorial to bypass this problem.

I need to make a new Point Type which can contain 15 other scalars as parameter in addition to its XYZ coordinates, its normals and its colors.

After that I import a new point cloud which is already written on my disk, which contains points with the same parameters. With this point type I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a bit here's how I solved it :

You DO NOT

```
#include <memory.h>
```

It seems to be deprecated for the reason I've mentionned.

I suggest you to follow [this tutorial](https://programmer.ink/think/add-custom-pointt-type-adding-your-own-custom-pointt-type.html)

Therefore if you create your own point type your code will look like this :

```
struct MyPointType
{
    PCL_ADD_POINT4D;                  // preferred way of adding a XYZ+padding
    PCL_ADD_RGB;                    //if you want to add colors, you'd better use that

    float the_exact_name_of_the_scalar1;
    float the_exact_name_of_the_scalar2;

    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW     // make sure our new allocators are aligned
} EIGEN_ALIGN16;                    // enforce SSE padding for correct memory alignment


POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT(MyPointType,           // here we assume a XYZ + "test" (as fields)
    (float, x, x)
    (float, y, y)
    (float, z, z)
    (float,rgb,rgb)                                      //colors
    (float, the_exact_name_of_the_scalar1, the_exact_name_of_the_scalar1)
    (float, the_exact_name_of_the_scalar2, the_exact_name_of_the_scalar2)
)
```

Then you can use MyPointType exactly like a classic point type.

With PCL 1.9 you should use

```
EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
```

instead of

```
PCL_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
```

Comment: How did you make it work with other functions or constructors?
For example MyPointType(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 2). Assuming my 4th parameter is a integer.